# Spring not recognising some @Configuration and @Component classes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have - or rather had - a working Spring application, running within IntelliJ. It contains several classes annotated with `@Configuration`, and several `@Component` beans. At some point, the following happened:

1. Intelli started showing errors in the code editor stating "*Could not autowire. No bean of 'xxx' type  found*". But there are such beans which are annotated with `@Component`.
2. Breakpoints in the constructor of specific `@Component` beans are not reached. But that is not true for all `@Component` beans.
3. When running in debug mode, breakpoints in certain `@Configuration` files are not reached, even though the debugger was stopping there before. The application will fail if it is autowired with one of these `@Component` beans.
4. The application starts without errors, but obviously without several beans configured in `@Configuration` classes being called.

The class which contains the main method which runs the Spring Boot application is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`. `@Component` classes which live in the same package as this class are recognised and can be autowired, even into classes in other packages.

I am not aware of anything in the code or project which would have changed.

Under **File -> Project Settings -> Modules**, under **Spring Application Context** have now selected all `@Configuration` files. However this makes no difference.

Have also tried **Build -> Rebuild Project**.

The packages in which the classes reside have not changed. Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Thanks

Comment: It would be useful to see some code examples or package structure here. This could help to figure out the problem. In most cases packages are not scanned. Interesting would be the configuration and Application classes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If few classes are not getting recognised @Component. Then it could be the case that those classes don't come under the same package. You must have observed that the classes under the same package as of Main class of @SpringBootApplication, got recognised with @Component because @SpringBootApplication defines an automatic @ComponentScan on the package.

So other classes which were defined in some other package are not recognised because there is no @ComponentScan for those classes' package.

You can do the following to get those classes recognised(add the other packages which are not directly under the hierarchy of @SpringBootApplication):

```
@ComponentScan({"com.example.springboot.anything","com.example.springboot.somethingelse"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class AnySpringBootApplication {
```

Comment: Upvoting.  Is there an "official link" to this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure it will not be a common case, but for me the problem was that my class had a relatively generic name. Although it was located in the package mentioned in the ComponentScan, on the same level with other classes all found and used, I kept having problems that the ApplicationContext failed to load. After I renamed the class it worked, I found that two other classes in org.springframework had the same name.